# Oracle: Pivoting data into date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in the following format:

```
Date           Quantity
-----------------------
1-Jan-2014      5 
6-Jan-2014      15
10-Jan-2014     67
21-Jan-2014     42
```

What Oracle SQL can I use to produce the result:

```
StartDate     EndDate      Quantity
----------------------------------
1-Jan-2014   5-Jan-2014    5
6-Jan-2014   9-Jan-2014    15
10-Jan-2014  20-Jan-2014   67
21-Jan-2014  null          67
```

I'm thinking along the lines of using RANK OVER PARTITION with a join against a subquery for R = R+1 then doing StartDate-1 for the EndDate but can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Your approach should work. Show us your attempted query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LEAD function to get the next row and subtract one from it.

```
select date as startdate,
       lead(date) over (order by date) - 1 as enddate,
       quantity
  from table;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/861632/2)</kbd>

Comment: **Legend!**  Thanks for teaching me something new!  A very elegant solution - I really appreciate the time in setting up a SQLFiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if the following query works.

```
SELECT Left.Date "StartDate",
    (right.Date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) "EndDate",
    Left.Quantity
FROM 
    (
         SELECT t1.Date, 
             t1.Quantity,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.DATE ASC) "rank"
         FROM Table t1 
    ) as Left
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
         SELECT t1.Date,
             t1.Quantity,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.DATE ASC) "rank"
         FROM Table t1 
    ) as Right ON Left.rank = Right.rank - 1
```

Comment: Many thanks - I got this working correctly initially but then just as I was about to accept your answer I was introduced to the **LAG** function.  I think you have to agree with the elegance of **LAG** by Eat A Peach.